# Powershell Get values listed

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get values from a hashtable but i'm having some difficulty with that.

`$allMediafiles` is a Hashtable.

This is my code:

```
$AllDoc =  ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name -eq 'document'}).Group

$obj2 = [pscustomobject]@{
    'FileTypes' = ($AllDoc.video_audio | Group ).Name; 
    'Format' = ($AllDoc.Format | Group).Values ;
    'O_OpenAccess' = ($AllDoc | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "O_OpenAccess"}).count; 
    'U_UserAccess' = ($AllDoc | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "U_UserAccess"}).count; 
    'S_SubscriberAccess' = ($AllDoc | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "S_SubscriberAccess"}).count;
    'REVIEW_ELDP' = ($AllDoc | Group-Object "SecurityTag" | ? {$_.Name -eq "REVIEW_ELDP"}).count;
}
```

My result:

```
FileTypes Format           O_OpenAccess U_UserAccess S_SubscriberAccess REVIEW_ELDP
--------- ------           ------------ ------------ ------------------ -----------
document  {eaf, pfsx, pdf}            0           17                  2           0
```

I need something like this:

```
FileTypes Format           O_OpenAccess U_UserAccess S_SubscriberAccess REVIEW_ELDP
--------- ------           ------------ ------------ ------------------ -----------
document  eaf                        0           14                  1           0
          pfsx                       0            3                  0           0
          pdf                        0            0                  1           0
```

Thanks for any help!!

```
$Alldoc =

video_audio SecurityTag        Duration Format
----------- -----------        -------- ------
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    S_SubscriberAccess          eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                pfsx  
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    U_UserAccess                pfsx  
document    U_UserAccess                pfsx  
document    U_UserAccess                pfsx  
document    U_UserAccess                eaf   
document    S_SubscriberAccess          pdf   
document    U_UserAccess                eaf
```

Comment: Can you add the value of `$AllDoc` to the question body?

Comment: Yes, No problem! Sorry, My bad, @Andrew

Comment: Are you sure `$AllDoc` is a Hashtable and not (as it appears to be) an array of PSObjects?

Comment: @Theo, Sorry, you right. The $AllDoc variable is a array of PSObjects, result of an Hashtable  $allMediaFiles. $AllDoc =  ($allMediaFiles | Group-Object "video_audio" | ? {$_.name -eq 'document'}).Group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to call `Group-Object` once more - to group the records by `Format` - then loop over the results:

```
foreach($format in $Alldoc |Group-Object -Property Format)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        # Just grab the first one - they're all identical
        'FileTypes' = $format.Group[0].video_audio
        # Grab the format Name from when we grouped them
        'Format' = $format.Name
        # For the remaining ones, simply count the number of occurences
        'O_OpenAccess' = @($format.Group |? {$_.SecurityTag -eq "O_OpenAccess"}).Count
        'U_UserAccess' = @($format.Group |? {$_.SecurityTag -eq "U_UserAccess"}).Count 
        'S_SubscriberAccess' = @($format.Group |? {$_.SecurityTag -eq "S_SubscriberAccess"}).Count
        'REVIEW_ELDP' = @($format.Group |? {$_.SecurityTag -eq "REVIEW_ELDP"}).Count
    }
}
```